# Extracting audio from picture of time-domain signal

Tags: image-processing, audio, spectrogram, time-domain

I saw this nifty art thing where they dress up the time-domain audio signal in some pretty way.
https://www.etsy.com/ArtbloxShop/listing/621561709/sound-wave-art-custom-soundwave-print

My question is whether I can take a photograph of that object and somehow reconstruct the actual audio?  I'm assuming that the printing and my photograph won't have the resolution to directly capture the wave data points.  But I was wondering if using some basic assumptions about frequency if we could reconstruct something crude.  I suspect that too much information is lost, but I was hoping there might be some clever tricks.

There is clearly some resolution of printing that would preserve enough information, but I'm wondering if we're talking about a poster-sized version of a short clip or something.  That wouldn't be very practical.  It would be fun to have time-domain audio hanging as art if I could take my smart phone and take a picture of it, and after some processing, play back the audio.

As an alternative, could this be done using a spectrogram?  Like if that block of art displayed that instead?  Or maybe some combination of that plus time-domain envelope?  If I did want to represent audio as an image as part of art (maybe presume something around 8.5x11 size), is there some way I could have an app photograph it and turn it back to audio?

Comment: Related question: [How to transform SoundWave Picture to sound?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/how-to-transform-soundwave-picture-to-sound/44745#44745)

Comment: Like this?  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BZgE2e4Y3As

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general no, there is way too much information lost

If you can constrain the audio to a reasonably small corpus of songs, phrase, keywords, etc. you may be able to train a neural network to recognize the basic envelope shape. There used to be an app that was trying to do something like this, but I can't find it anymore.